# Generating rotating groups for a seminar

Tags: combinatorics, recreational-mathematics, puzzle, combinatorial-designs

One of my teachers is planning a seminar for his English class and he asked me if there was a way to generate the groups for the days other than brute-force random generating. I really think there should be a way, but I can't think of something.

Here is the situation:

- There are 18 kids and 22 days
- Each seminar has a group of 12 and a group of 6
- Goals:

  - Maximize the variety of students in groups (i.e. that aren't always in the same or nearly same group of people)
  - Ensure all students are in the second group the same amount $\pm 1$ times

I was hoping to find a way of solving the problem instead of find just a solution. Basically I have two questions:

1. Does anyone know how this can be done?
2. Does anyone have any resources/similar problems/methods that I can look at that might help me solve this?

Comment: The belongs to "design theory" and there are basic theorems that give necessary conditions.

Comment: Can't be done. The second goal is unachievable. You want the students to be part of the larger group with twice as much probability as the smaller group. A simple example: say you have 3 students, in 4 days, and each one of them is alone half of the time, while the others are in a group. So first student is alone 2 days, the second is alone two different days, and the third is alone another two days. But 6 days is more than 4.

Comment: @Andrei What I actually meant for the second goal is that everyone is in the second group (the one of six) the same number of times. I.e.If there were 18 days everyone would be in the second group 6 times. What I want is that the every student is in the second group $\pm 1$ times

Answer (score 0):

When I was young I caused problems for my English teachers so I think now is time to thenk them. :-)

> Maximize the variety of students in groups (i.e. that aren't always in the same or nearly same group of people)

A straightforward measure of the variety of students in groups $G_1$ and $G_2$ is the size of their intersection $G_1\cap G_2$. Since the big groups are the complements to the small groups, (for both goals) it suffices to deal only with the small groups. So, given $d$ ($22$) days, for the first goal we want to minimize

$$s=1+\max\{|G_i\cap G_j|: 1\le i<j\le d\}.$$

That is no subset of $s$ students can belong to distinct (small) groups. If we have $n$ ($18$) students then there are ${n\choose s}$ such subsets. On the other hand, each of $d$ groups of size $k$ ($6$) provides ${k\choose s}$ such subsets, and all of them are distinct. So we have $d{k\choose s}\le {n\choose s}$, which implies that for our situation $s\ge 3=t$.

We can try to achieve the first goal by taking a part of a [Steiner system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_system) $S(t,k,n)$. Unfortunately, in our case $(t,k,n)=(3,6,18)$, and the respective Steiner system does not exist, because [$b$ is not integer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_system#Properties). I tried to recall a combinatorial design with $18$ base elements, which can be used to create a seminar schedule, but I failed.

So I used geometric imagination and constructed a schedule for $24$ days where the students are represented by edges and faces of the cube. The first $12$ days are represented by pairs of adjacent faces of the cube and a schedule for each day is a union of two day’s faces and four edges which are incident to exactly one vertex of these faces. The second $8$ days are represented by vertices of the cube and a schedule for each day is a union of edges and faces incident to day’s vertex. The last $4$ days are represented by pairs of opposite vertices of the cube and a schedule for each day consists of six edges which constitute a cycle not containing day’s vertices. This schedule is balanced, that is each student participates in exactly $8$ (small) groups. So to achieve the second goal it suffices to remove from this schedule two days with disjoint schedules. Such schedules can be taken as corresponding to opposite vertices from the second $8$ days.